# If $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable at $c \in \mathbb{R}$, show that $f'(c) =\lim (n(f(c + 1/n) - f (c))$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

> If $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable at $c \in
> > \mathbb{R}$, show that $f'(c) =\lim n(f(c + 1/n) - f (c))$  However
>   converse in not always true.

$\lim n(f(c + 1/n) - f (c)) = \lim \frac{f(c + 1/n) - f (c)}{1/n}$

Now $1/n > 0$ $1/n \to 0 \; as \; n \to \infty$

so let $h =1/n>0$ $h \to 0 ;as \; n \to \infty$

$\lim n(f(c + 1/n) - f (c)) = \lim_{h \to 0 } \frac{f(c + h) - f (c)}{h} = f'(c)$

Is this proof correct? I ask because my book has only given the definition of $f'(c)$ as $\lim_{x \to c} \frac{f(x) - f(c)}{x-c}$

Also how can I prove the other part, i.e., existence of the limit of this sequence does not guarantee the existence of $f'(c)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first part reasoning is almost correct, limit can be realized as sequential version: For every sequence $\{x_{n}\}$ such that $x_{n}\ne c$, $x_{n}\rightarrow c$, then $Q(x_{n})\rightarrow L$, where $Q$ is the difference quotient.

For the converse is not true: $f(x)=\chi_{\bf{Q}}(x)$, we have $f(1/n)-f(0)=0$ so the limit is zero but this function is not diffrentiable at $x=0$ because it is not continuous at $x=0$.

Comment: I am not aware of the function you mentioned is there a simpler function for the converse ?

Comment: Or you can try this: Let $f(1/n)=f(0)=0$ and $f(x)=1$ for all $x\in(1/(n+1),1/n)$, $n=1,2,...$. It is still the case that $f$ is not continuous at $x=0$.